# Multiple fields that are generated dynamically in drupal forms

Tags: javascript, php, forms, drupal-8

In a particular section of my form, some of fields are iterated over n number of times whenever we click add button n times.

I want to add below details of each student by click add button and remove the details by remove button.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
  $form['reg']= array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',          
          '#title' => 'Registration Number',
          '#validated' => TRUE,
      );
 $form['fname']= array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',          
          '#title' => 'First Name',
          '#validated' => TRUE,
 );
  $form['lname']= array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',          
          '#title' => 'last Name',
          '#validated' => TRUE,
  );
 $form['email'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => 'Email',
       '#validated' => TRUE
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Field Collection module with multiple values on the content type?

- Create a field of type Field Collection
- Allow the field to have multiple values.
- Add your fields.

See https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection for more info on the module and https://www.drupal.org/node/1353926 for documentation.